# MVC4 Seed Database Foreign Key by Id

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 classes which hold data for restaurants.

**Status.cs**

```
public class Status
{

    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Restaurant.cs**

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }



    // NAVIGATION PROPERTIES

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to seed data into the database.

First, I seed the status table, then I wish to seed the Restaurants table.

```
var statuses = new List<Status>
{
    new Status { Name = "Draft" },
    new Status { Name = "Live" },
    new Status { Name = "Invisible" },
    new Status { Name = "Discontinued" }
};
statuses.ForEach(a => context.Statuses.Add(a));

var restaurants = new List<Restaurant> 
{ 
    new Restaurant { Name = "The Restaurant Name", Email = "email@restaurant.com", Telephone = "012345566787", StatusId = 1 }
};
restaurants.ForEach(a=>context.Restaurants.Add(a));

base.seed(context);
```

This doesn't work, because it doesn't like the way I try to seed StatusId = 1 into Restaurant.

I know that I can create a new Status within the new Restaurant, however, I have already seeded the statuses into the database. How do I go about setting the Restaurant's Status to Draft???

Do I have to do this every time???

```
new Restaurant { Name = "The Restaurant Name", Email = "email@restaurant.com", Telephone = "012345566787", StatusId = new Status { Name = "Draft"} }
```

Will this not literally generate a new row in the status table called Status every time I create a new Restaurant with the status "Draft"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't set the `StatusId`, set the `Status`:

```
var restaurants = new List<Restaurant> 
{ 
    new Restaurant { 
        Name = "The Restaurant Name", 
        Email = "email@restaurant.com", 
        Telephone = "012345566787", 
        Status = statuses.Single(s=>s.Name=="Draft") }
};
```

That way the `StatusID` is set by the context and uses the same ID as the `Status`.

If you want to reference the Status in the list by Index (e.g. `statuses[0]` for `"Draft"`) that works too; selecting by name is more appropriate, though, IMHO.

**EDIT**

Just read the end of your question - so to answer that:

When you create a "new" `Status` and attach it to your `Restaurant`, the context doesn't know that you want to use the existing status of `"Draft"`, so it does what you tell it - creates a new one.  When you attach an existing `Status` from the context is used that ID since it's the same instance.

Comment: Aaaah, I get it now. Thank you. Working perfectly. 1 thing though, needs to be s.Name=="Draft" in your solution.